# warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

あるプログラムを実行すると以下の警告がでます。
解決方法を教えて欲しいです。
よろしくお願いします

```sh
FutureWarning: Using an implicitly registered datetime converter for a matplotlib plotting method. The converter was registered by pandas on import. Future versions of pandas will require you to explicitly register matplotlib converters.

To register the converters:
        >>> from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
        >>> register_matplotlib_converters()
  warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　一般に、エラーメッセージが同じでもプログラムによって対応方法が異なる場合があるので、可能であればこの警告が出るプログラムのサンプルも提供して頂きたいです。たとえば[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)をご覧ください。質問文下の「編集」から追記できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: これ [DEPR: Fixed warning for implicit registration #24964](http://1.pk4520.com/github_/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/24964) が関連しているかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

その処理を実行する前に、警告文の内容そのまま、以下を実行しておけばよいです。

```py
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
```